# Prove that the transpose of a matrix is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

Define $T: M_{m \times n}(\mathbb{R}) \to M_{n \times m}(\mathbb{R})$ by $T(A)=B$ where $b_{ji}=a_{ij}$.

I am having a confusion and lost with the notation for proving that this is a linear transformation. I will **indicate** below.

**Claim:** $T$ is a linear transformation.

**Proof:**

Let $A, B$ be $m \times n$ matrices where $A = a_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $B = b_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}$.

$(1)$ First we want to prove that $T(A+B)=T(A)+T(B). \bigstar$

**Version 1:**
Consider, $T((A+B))=(A+B)^T=(a_{ij}+b_{ij})^T=(a_{ij})^T+(b_{ij})^T=a_{ji}+b_{ji}=A^T+B^T=T(A)+T(B).$

**Version 2:** (Of the same proof above)

Consider, $T(A+B)=(A+B)^T=A^T+B^T=T(A)+T(B).$

In the proof above, I got from left hand side of the equation of $\bigstar$ to the right hand side of the equation. These two confuses me a little because how does one go from **$(A+B)^T=A^T+B^T$**? Why is this allowed? I feel that **version 1** explains why $(A+B)^T=A^T+B^T$  but I'm not exactly sure how. I think this is an issue with the notation. Any clarfication would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Looks fine, but you need to show that $T(\lambda A) = \lambda T (A)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 2: definitely wrong.  You have assumed that $(A+B)^T=A^T+B^T$, which is (part of) what you are supposed to prove.

Version 1: with
$$(a_{ij}+b_{ij})^T=(a_{ij})^T+b_{ij})^T$$
you have done exactly the same thing.  You could do better simply by leaving this out:
$$T((A+B))=(A+B)^T=(a_{ij}+b_{ij})^T=a_{ji}+b_{ji}=A^T+B^T=T(A)+T(B)\ .$$
I still have a bit of a problem with this, as you appear to be saying that $A$, a matrix, is the same as $a_{ij}$, a single entry in that matrix.  It doesn't hurt at all to use words in your proof, so how about something like this:
$$\eqalign{
  \hbox{$(i,j)$ element of $(A+B)^T$}
  &=\hbox{$(j,i)$ element of $A+B$}\qquad\hbox{(definition of transpose)}\cr
  &=\hbox{$(j,i)$ element of $A$}+\hbox{$(j,i)$ element of $B$}\cr
  &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\hbox{(definition of matrix addition)}\cr
  \hbox{$(i,j)$ element of $A^T+B^T$}
  &=\hbox{$(i,j)$ element of $A^T$}+\hbox{$(i,j)$ element of $B^T$}\cr
  &=\hbox{$(j,i)$ element of $A$}+\hbox{$(j,i)$ element of $B$}\ .\cr}$$
Since this is true for all $i,j$, we have $(A+B)^T=A^T+B^T$.

BTW, as you are using $T$ to indicate transpose, it would be a really good idea to use a different letter for your linear transformation.

Comment: @DylanJ I have to tell you that on an exam, version 2 would definitely not receive full credit if I was marking it, because it is essentially a circular argument.  The property you refer to is what is being asked in the question, and the suggested argument is basically "it's true because it's true".

Comment: That's a very clear proof, thank you so much for the your proof that you provided me with! I was very lost to what type of notation I should use for this but now it's very clear. And no confusion whatsoever. Thanks again. Yes, I am a student :D